# Правка всплывающего плеера YouTube

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

Использую такую конструкцию для просмотра видео. Очень удобно и сокращается время загрузки страницы.

```js
document.getElementById("video").onclick = function() {
 var id = this.dataset.id;
 theIframe = document.createElement('iframe');
 theIframe.src = '//www.youtube.com/embed/' + id + '?rel=0&autoplay=1&showinfo=0';
 theIframe.onclick = function () {this.parentElement.removeChild(this);};
 this.parentNode.insertBefore(theIframe, this.nextSibling);
}
```

```css
.video-block {
  width: 280px;
  height: 160px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#video + iframe {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 11;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: solid rgba(0,0,0,.9);
    border-width: 8vh 5vw;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="video-block" id="video" data-id="xcJtL7QggTI" style="background-image: url(//img.youtube.com/vi/xcJtL7QggTI/mqdefault.jpg)"></div>
```

*При вставке кода сюда, почему-то постоянно меняется id, но не суть важно, общий принцип понятен.*

[Тут](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VPLXOb) есть рабочий вариант этого кода.

Вопросов в общем-то два. Как добавить возможность развернуть видео на всю ширину экрана? Если добавить в `theIframe.src` allowfullscreen, ничего не меняется.

Второй вопрос, добавление кнопки/иконки закрыть. Можно ли её добавить каким-то способом при нынешнем коде? Или необходимо перед созданием iframe создать блок в который будет вложен плеер и уже блоку задать стиль затемнения, кнопку закрывания блока и т.д.? Как лучше и проще реализовать этот момент?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Вам нужно на всю страницу или на весь экран? А с закрытием: можно с этим кодом создавать ещё один блок, при клике на который будет закрываться видео

Comment: Да, нужно на весь экран, стандартный функционал плеера (правая нижняя кнопка). Она сейчас не активна, возможно из-за того, что плеер создается не во время загрузки страницы. По закрытию примерно понятно, или отдельно иконку создать и поместить её в угол, или вложить iframe в блок. Основной вопрос по allowfullscreen.

Comment: Да, я об этом написал. Почему-то на этом сайте ID постоянно подменяется. [Тут](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VPLXOb) можно поглядеть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что у вас в iframe нету разрешения на разворачивание. Вам нужно добавить эту строку в открытие iframe: `theIframe.setAttribute("allowfullscreen", "true")`

Вот рабочий пример: [jsfiddle-e7mx3ze0](https://jsfiddle.net/yuri_spivak/e7mx3ze0/)

Comment: О, это то, что я искал. точнее пытался добавить атрибут в `.src`, как при обычной вставке, а его нужно было добавить через `.setAttribute`, даже не подумал об этом. Спасибо большое)